# htaccess: combining mod_geoip and mod_rewrite for security

Tags: apache, .htaccess, security, mod-rewrite

As a mental health therapist, it is important to have an available and stable website, the corona crisis taught me. Due to intensive hacking attempts of foreign IP addresses, I have had to take drastic measures and now restrict access to my site to only two countries using mod_geoip in my htaccess file.

All visitors outside these two countries are redirected to another site.

```
<IfModule mod_geoip.c>
GeoIPEnable On
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE BE PermitCountry
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE NL PermitCountry
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^(AF|AX)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://goto.some-other.site/$1 [L]
Allow from env=PermitCountry
</IfModule>
```

This works fine, but with this negative consequence, that my site is no longer indexed by Google, Bing,... So I looked for the lists of urls used by Google and Bing and wanted to allow them to access my site.

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
Allow from 34.100.182.96/28 
#Example for Google
Allow from 157.55.39.0/24  
#Example for Bing
</IfModule>
```

But, how do I combine both inside my htaccess, allowing just users from these two countries and allowing the crawlers to access my site?

I tried this, without any real result: the site is not accessible in Search console and webmaster tools. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<IfModule mod_geoip.c>
GeoIPEnable On
#Add countries you wish to permit here
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE BE PermitCountry
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE NL PermitCountry
RewriteEngine on
#Allow Google
Allow from 34.100.182.96/28
#Allow Bing
Allow from 157.55.39.0/24   
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^(AF|AX)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://goto.some-other.site/$1 [L]
Allow from env=PermitCountry
</IfModule>
```

The site needs to be accessible in search console and webmaster tools; and only accessible in the BE and NL countries.

Comment: What version of Apache are you on?

Comment: Apache version 2.4